# Neural Net - Feed Forward, Matrix Multiplication in C#

Tags: c#, python, numpy, neural-network, matrix-multiplication

I'm attempting to make a Neural Network in C#, I based the design in a python code I made a while back. But somehow the end result is not the same.

I'm new to C# and I'm using it in Unity, so I have limitation to library uses.

In python numpy can do matrix multiplications with the numpy.dot() method. I Haven't found something similar in C#, especially in Unity. So I had to do it by hand.

The Python code:

```
import numpy as np

class NN:
    def __init__(self, n_input, n_hidden_layers, n_hidden_nodes, n_output):
        self.weights_hidden = []
        for n in range(n_hidden_layers + 1):
            if n == 0:
                size = n_input, n_hidden_nodes
            elif n == n_hidden_layers:
                size = n_hidden_nodes, n_output
            else:
                size = n_hidden_nodes, n_hidden_nodes

            self.weights_hidden.append(
                np.random.random(size)
            )

    @staticmethod
    def activation(x):
        return np.tanh(x)

    def feed_forward(self, ip):
        input_values = (ip - np.mean(ip, axis=0)) / np.std(ip, axis=0)
        for w, weights in enumerate(self.weights_hidden):
            if w == 0:
                result = input_values

            result = np.array(
                map(self.activation, result.dot(weights))
            )

        return result

ANN = NN(n_input=5, n_hidden_layers=2, n_hidden_nodes=3, n_output=1)
print ANN.feed_forward([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

My attempt to convert it to C#.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class neural_net : MonoBehaviour {
    int n_inputs;
    int n_hidden_layers;
    int n_hidden_nodes;
    int n_outputs;


    float[] inputs;

    ArrayList hidden_weights;
    ArrayList hidden_results;

    float[] output_results;


    public void init(int n_inputs, int n_hidden_layers, int n_hidden_nodes, int n_outputs){
        this.n_inputs = n_inputs;
        this.n_hidden_layers = n_hidden_layers;
        this.n_hidden_nodes = n_hidden_nodes;
        this.n_outputs = n_outputs;

        this.hidden_weights = new ArrayList ();
        this.hidden_results = new ArrayList ();
        this.output_results = new float[n_outputs];

        int rows;
        int columns;
        for (int h = 0; h < n_hidden_layers + 2; h++) {
            if (h == 0){
                // input -> hidden
                rows = n_inputs;
                columns = n_hidden_nodes;
            }
            else if(h == n_hidden_layers + 1){
                // hidden -> output
                rows = n_hidden_nodes;
                columns = n_outputs;
            }
            else {
                // hidden -> hidden
                rows = n_hidden_nodes;
                columns = n_hidden_nodes;
            }

            float[] hidden_result = new float[rows*columns];
            hidden_results.Add(hidden_results);


            float[,] target = new float[rows,columns];

            string test = "";
            for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++){
                for(int c = 0; c < columns; c++){
                    target[r,c] = Random.Range(0.0f, 1.0f);
                    test += target[r,c] + ", ";
                }
            }
            hidden_weights.Add(target);
        }
    }


    float activation(float x){
        // tanh(x);
        return (1 - Mathf.Exp (-2 * x)) / (1 + Mathf.Exp (-2 * x));
    }


    float[] _dot_matrix(float[] results, float[,] weights){
        float[] new_matrix = new float[weights.GetLength(1)];

        string t0 = "";
        for (int r = 0; r < weights.GetLength(1); r++){
            float res = 0;
            for (int c = 0; c < weights.GetLength(0); c++) {
                res += results[c] * weights[c,r];
            }
            new_matrix[r] = res;
        }
        return new_matrix;
    }


    float[] _map_activation(float[] pre_results){
        float[] results = new float[pre_results.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < results.Length; i++) {
            results[i] = activation(pre_results[i]);
        }
        return results;
    }


    float[] feed_forward(){
        int h;
        for (h = 0; h < n_hidden_layers + 2; h++) {
            float[] dot_matrix_result;
            if(h == 0){
                dot_matrix_result = _dot_matrix(inputs, (float[,])hidden_weights[h]);
            }
            else if (h == n_hidden_layers +1){
                dot_matrix_result = _dot_matrix((float[])hidden_results[h-1], (float[,])hidden_weights[h]);
                output_results = _map_activation(dot_matrix_result);
                break;
            }
            else {
                dot_matrix_result = _dot_matrix((float[])hidden_results[h-1], (float[,])hidden_weights[h]);
            }
            float[] result = _map_activation(dot_matrix_result);
            hidden_results[h] = _map_activation(result);
        }

        return output_results;
    }


    float[] normalize_input(float[] inputs){
        float sum = 0.0f;
        for (int i = 0; i < inputs.Length; i++) {
            sum += inputs[i] ;
        }
        float average = sum / inputs.Length;



        float[] deviations = new float[inputs.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < inputs.Length; i++) {
            deviations[i] = Mathf.Pow(inputs[i] - average,2);
        }

        float sum_deviation = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < deviations.Length; i++) {
            sum_deviation += deviations[i];
        }

        float variance = sum_deviation / deviations.Length;

        float std = Mathf.Sqrt (variance);

        for (int i = 0; i < inputs.Length; i++) {
            inputs[i] = (inputs[i] - average)/std;
        }

        return inputs;
    }

    public void start_net(float[] inputs){
        this.inputs = normalize_input(inputs);
        feed_forward ();
    }
}
```

I run the net from other script using the init method and then the start_net() method.

I made a test with not random weights and fixed input data, but it didn't came to the same result as the python code.

What's wrong with the C# code?

Comment: There are plenty of C# matrix and array libraries—Math.NET, CSML, etc. So you really don't need to reinvent the wheel here any more than you did in Python.

Comment: I haven't found a working library which works with Unity.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "works with Unity". Matrices are matrices; matrix math is matrix math.

Comment: I mean, I don't know how to use this libraries with Unity. I'm new to C#, I only have the MonoDevelop installed.

Comment: I don't know how to explain how to install and use third-party libraries for C#. If you'd rather reinvent the wheel, of course you can do so. And this a perfectly legitimate question to ask. (It might be better if you reduced it to a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), however. You're really just asking for help with your `dot` function, not your whole program.)